# Regular expression and accents

Tags: regex

This issue is driving me crazy
I need to exclude this words with accents and I am having problems. Specially I think that the `\b` doesnt work good with letters with accent like áéíóúñ
For example, I have this regex:

```
\b(m[ií]s*|m[ií][ao]s*|t[úu]s*|s[u]s*)\b
```

The words:

mi - match

mí - dont match

mias - match

mías - dont match

I try to use `\s` instead of `\b` but I match spaces
How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to match only words that *don't* have accents?

Comment: Could the string you are trying to match only look like it has accents? As in HTML escaped characters instead?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match all words that don't have any accented letters:

```
\b[a-zA-Z']+\b
```

Including the quote char means words with apostrophes - eg "can't" - are also matched.

Note that the regex expression `\w` is not suitable because it includes digits and the underscore character.

Comment: Yes. But I am needing to match words with accent, like tú and tus and mí and mís.     BUT not mísa

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're using java, accents are considered non-word characters so you can detect with \w vs \W. This may be the case with whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match unicode characters, which may be more or less complicated depending on the language you are using. This link might help you understand better :

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments is sounds like:

- Given the string: mi, tú, tus, mí, mís, mias, Yes. But I am needing to match words with accent, like tú and tus and mí and mís. BUT not mísa –
- Match : mi, tú, tus, mí, mís, mias
- Don't Match: mías

This powershell shows the match string is working for all the cases you've listed

```
$Matches = @()
$String = 'mi, tú, tus, mí, mís, mias, Yes. But I am needing to match words with accent, like tú and tus and mí and mís. BUT not mísa – '
([regex]'(?=\b)(mí|m[ií]s*|m[ií][ao]s*|t[úu]s*|s[u]s*)(?=\b)').matches($String) | foreach {
    write-host "at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'"
    } # next match
```

yields

```
at 0 = 'mi'
at 4 = 'tú'
at 8 = 'tus'
at 13 = 'mí'
at 17 = 'mís'
at 22 = 'mias'
at 83 = 'tú'
at 90 = 'tus'
at 98 = 'mí'
at 105 = 'mís'
```